# Access map's value if its key exists C++

Tags: c++, dictionary

I am trying to access the value of map at a specific key so long as that key exists.

To check that the key exists, I have:

```
if (pos.find(test[i]) != pos.end())
```

Inside of the if statement I wish to increment my counter as such:

```
posProb *= pos[test[i]]->second;
```

The entire function is set up as this:

```
void compute(vector<string> test, map<string, double> pos, map<string, double> neg) {
double posProb = 1, negProb = 1;

for (int i = 0; i < test.size(); i++) {
    if (pos.find(test[i]) != pos.end())                     
        posProb *= pos[test[i]]->second * UNDERFLOWVAR;
    else posProb *= pos.find("UNK")->second * UNDERFLOWVAR;
}
cout << posProb;
```

How can I adjust what I currently have so that I can appropriately access the second variable (value) of my map?

Comment: Your initial value is 0, so all you're doing is multiplying by 0.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie That was my second problem! Thank you for catching that!

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
auto unk = pos["UNK"];
for (int i = 0; i < test.size(); i++) {
    auto it = pos.find(test[i]);               
    posProb *= (it != pos.end() ? it->second : unk) * UNDERFLOWVAR;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `find` already failed so maybe you want something like:

```
void compute(vector<string> test, map<string, double> pos, map<string, double> neg) {
double posProb = 0, negProb = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < test.size(); i++) {
    if (pos.find(test[i]) != pos.end()) {
        posProb *= pos[test[i]]->second * UNDERFLOWVAR;
    {
    else {
        if (pos.find("UNK") == pos.end()) {
            pos("UNK") = 1; //??
        }
        posProb *= pos.find("UNK")->second * UNDERFLOWVAR;
    }
}
cout << posProb;
```

Comment: When I keep pos[test[i]]->second, I receive "Error: expression must have pointer type"

Comment: @Shannon sorry, fixed that

Comment: I just tried something different and on the surface it appears to be functioning as expected. I now have `pos[test[i]]` without the `->second`.